# Share Point 2013 url resolve after web app extend

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping, ssl, dns, iis7

I have deployed SP 2013 WA in intranet with http://abc.de.fg that is working fine, 
after that I have extended that WA to https://kl.mn.op all are working fine but pictures and some html links are still pointing to old intranet url that is http

SSL is working correctly this could be alternate access mapping I have tried with many ways on AAM but problem persist.

DNS entry is also fine because I can access my site on https with right user id and password. But may be some issue that I dont know ?

Any reply will be appriciated.

Comment: I have a Similar problem.. My AAM are working fine... i have an Extranet & Default Zone for MySite and Portal. The problem is when I am on the Portal Extranet, the MySite Url is still pointing on the Default Zone URL... If I'm going on mySite in the Extranet Zone, the Urls of the portal are still in the Default Zone... What's wrong ? Thanks, Charles !